# Superimpose charts in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to superimpose charts in the javascript library highcharts?
The columns can be the same width, it doesn't matter. But something that looks like this?  (image is screenshot from python matplotlib)

[image]

From what I have found in other SO threads [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441520/highcharts-combine-superimpose-columns) and from my own experimentation, it is not clear that I can.

What I'd really like to do is just draw one chart, then draw the next one over it. It would make my life much more simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use two series with disabled `grouping` and `groupPadding`:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            grouping: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [...],
        groupPadding: 0
    }, {
        data: [...]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gfj16908/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.grouping